# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent multiple select preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is string while replacement is an array

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I've seen multiple different answers to this question, none of which keep the use of form model binding. It seems like the form is submitting tags as an array, which actually should be a string. Any ideas?

Controller:

```
/**
 * Save new news
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function store(NewsRequest $request)
{
    // Create News object and save all form data
    $news = News::create($request->all());

// Rename image file and move to public/images
$image = $request->file('image');
$path = "/images/";
$ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$name = str_random(12) . $ext;
$image->move(public_path() . $path, $name);
$news->image = $path . $name;

// Save new image path to News object
$news->save();

//associate with sandbox, if not already
$news->sandboxes()->sync($request->input('sandboxes'));

//populate news_tag pivot table with chosen tags
$news->tags()->sync($request->input('tags'));



return redirect()->action('FP\NewsController@index');
}
```

Here's my trace:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 747:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
in helpers.php line 747
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array', '/home/greg/Projects/Code/sandboxserver/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php', '747', array('search' => '\?', 'replace' => array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), 'subject' => 'insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fafeafadfa, hgtshjnfxsnbdg, https://www.thing.com, 2016-11-12 21:30, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 'value' => array('1', '2')))
at preg_replace('/\?/', array('1', '2'), 'insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fafeafadfa, hgtshjnfxsnbdg, https://www.thing.com, 2016-11-12 21:30, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', '1') in helpers.php line 747
at str_replace_array('\?', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), 'insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fafeafadfa, hgtshjnfxsnbdg, https://www.thing.com, 2016-11-12 21:30, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)') in QueryException.php line 56
at QueryException->formatMessage('insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), object(PDOException)) in QueryException.php line 39
at QueryException->__construct('insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), object(PDOException)) in Connection.php line 730
at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 685
at Connection->run('insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 458
at Connection->statement('insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53')) in Connection.php line 414
at Connection->insert('insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53')) in Processor.php line 32
at Processor->processInsertGetId(object(Builder), 'insert into `news` (`title`, `author`, `url`, `publish_at`, `tags`, `snippet`, `content`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), 'id') in Builder.php line 2107
at Builder->insertGetId(array('fafeafadfa', 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'https://www.thing.com', '2016-11-12 21:30', array('1', '2'), 'gdsagasgbvsa', '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', object(UploadedFile), '2016-11-13 01:31:53', '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), 'id')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'insertGetId'), array(array('title' => 'fafeafadfa', 'author' => 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'url' => 'https://www.thing.com', 'publish_at' => '2016-11-12 21:30', 'tags' => array('1', '2'), 'snippet' => 'gdsagasgbvsa', 'content' => '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', 'image' => object(UploadedFile), 'updated_at' => '2016-11-13 01:31:53', 'created_at' => '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), 'id')) in Builder.php line 1423
at Builder->__call('insertGetId', array(array('title' => 'fafeafadfa', 'author' => 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'url' => 'https://www.thing.com', 'publish_at' => '2016-11-12 21:30', 'tags' => array('1', '2'), 'snippet' => 'gdsagasgbvsa', 'content' => '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', 'image' => object(UploadedFile), 'updated_at' => '2016-11-13 01:31:53', 'created_at' => '2016-11-13 01:31:53'), 'id')) in Model.php line 1628
at Model->insertAndSetId(object(Builder), array('title' => 'fafeafadfa', 'author' => 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'url' => 'https://www.thing.com', 'publish_at' => '2016-11-12 21:30', 'tags' => array('1', '2'), 'snippet' => 'gdsagasgbvsa', 'content' => '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', 'image' => object(UploadedFile), 'updated_at' => '2016-11-13 01:31:53', 'created_at' => '2016-11-13 01:31:53')) in Model.php line 1597
at Model->performInsert(object(Builder), array()) in Model.php line 1488
at Model->save() in Model.php line 574
at Model::create(array('_token' => 'dz4MGABUXPSV2fyT4rYcatpEcOnDVkjL0RX9tX9B', 'title' => 'fafeafadfa', 'author' => 'hgtshjnfxsnbdg', 'url' => 'https://www.thing.com', 'publish_at' => '2016-11-12 21:30', 'sandboxes' => array('1'), 'tags' => array('1', '2'), 'snippet' => 'gdsagasgbvsa', 'content' => '<p>bgsagsghsghsgb</p>', 'image' => object(UploadedFile))) in NewsController.php line 56
at NewsController->store(object(NewsRequest))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(NewsController), 'store'), array(object(NewsRequest))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(NewsRequest))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(NewsController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(NewsController), object(Route), object(Request), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\FP\NewsController', 'store') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 51
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/home/greg/Projects/Code/sandboxserver/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Why do you have `tags` field in your `news` table?

Comment: Team decided on news instead of articles.. Going to be renaming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple answer, had tags field inside of the "News" eloquent model since our previous team had tags as a table column >.> . All fixed now once I removed it!